# Изменить HTML код на WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Сайт на WordPress, состоит из блоков `PHP`. Через инструменты разработчика <kbd>F12</kbd> в браузере я вижу страницу `HTML`.

Требуется внести небольшие изменения в `HTML` код. Как это сделать, если у меня в папке сайта только `PHP` файлы?

Comment: Php создан для того, чтобы генерировать html.

Comment: я догадывался об этом :) как бы внести маленькие коррективы в конечный файл

Comment: Вам правильно отвечают - создайте дочернюю тему (иначе ваши правки слетят при обновлении темы), и вносите правки в php. Лучше это делать по ftp, не через админку WordPress (иначе можно радостно залочить сайт при ошибке).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вдумчиво читаем [Кодекс wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC) на предмет того, как устроены темы. Далее находим в подключенной у вас теме нужный шаблон и правим его. А ещё лучше - создаём [дочернюю тему](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B).

Comment: спасибо, буду копать в эту сторону

Comment: я создал дочернюю тему, теперь могу вносить изменения в стили.. но я так и не нашел доступ к html, видимо они хранятся в базе данных на сервере создателя темы?

Comment: Нет. Vital Max был прав, html-код хранится в шаблонах с расширением ".php". Это сделано для интеграции как собственно html-кода, так и встроенных в вордпресс функций. Нужный вам код находится в одном из php шаблонов. Дайте уже ссылку на ваш сайт и укажите кусочек кода, где "нужно всего лишь написать col2 вместо col3".

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил очень просто. Добавил стиль для конкретного id

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите через настройки в редактор тем - там можно изменить HTML любой части страницы.

Comment: Через редактор править шаблоны не советует даже сам wordpress. ))

Comment: в том то и дело, что в редакторе одни php файлы..

Comment: а мне нужно всего лишь написать col2 вместо col3 в классе блока.

Comment: PHP-файлы представляют собой смесь как PHP, так и HTML. Это нужно для того, чтобы не менять каждый файл отдельно, к примеру, после изменения названия сайта. Просто найдите там col2 (с помощью Ctrl+F) и замените на col3.

Comment: "а мне нужно всего лишь написать col2 вместо col3 в классе блока."
Вы, судя по всему, пока не очень разбираетесь в движке wordpress и тема сайта у вас стандартная, ну или установленная на выбор. Такие темы обычно поддерживают - обновляют. Если вы исправите файл темы, то или не сможете обновлять её, или после обновлений, ваши изменения в теме будут стёрты. Смотрите в сторону создания дочерней темы.